# How to test spring batch job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-batch

I'm trying to test a job but I can't get to the bottom of it, basically my step consists of a single reader and a composite Processor and a Composite writer, all this because I have to read from a single .CSV and write on MongoDB and Mysql,
here is my Job Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public  MarketDataMySqlRepository marketDataMySqlRepository;


    @Value("${file.input}")
    private String fileInput;




    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("customerInfoThreads-");
        return taskExecutor;
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<MarketDataDto> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MarketDataDto>().name("ItemReader")
                .resource(new PathResource(fileInput)).delimited()
                .names("time","id", "price", "quantity", "isbuyermaker")
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MarketDataDto>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(MarketDataDto.class);
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoItemWriter<MarketDataMongo> writer(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {

        return new MongoItemWriterBuilder<MarketDataMongo>().template(mongoTemplate).collection("marketdata")
                .build();

    }
    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<MarketDataMySql> writer1() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<MarketDataMySql> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRepository(marketDataMySqlRepository);
        writer.setMethodName("save");
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter CompositeItemWriter(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
        CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
        writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(writer(mongoTemplate),writer1()));
        return writer;
    }


    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessorMongo MongoProcessor() {
        return new UserItemProcessorMongo();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessorMySql MySqlProcessor() {return new UserItemProcessorMySql();}


    @Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor() throws Exception {
        List<ItemProcessor<MarketDataDto,MarketDataMongo>> itemProcessors = new ArrayList<>(1);
        List<ItemProcessor<MarketDataDto,MarketDataMySql>> itemProcessors1 = new ArrayList<>(1);
        itemProcessors1.add(MySqlProcessor());
        itemProcessors.add(MongoProcessor());
        CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor();
        processor.setDelegates(itemProcessors);
        processor.setDelegates(itemProcessors1);
        //processor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return processor;

    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(FlatFileItemReader<MarketDataDto> itemReader, MongoItemWriter<MarketDataMongo> itemWriter, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate)
            throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").chunk(200000).reader(itemReader)
                .processor(compositeProcessor()).writer(CompositeItemWriter(mongoTemplate)).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Job updateUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1)
            throws Exception {

        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("updateMarketJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener).start(step1).build();
    }

    }
```

And this is my TestClass :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {BatchConfiguration.class, BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BatchConfigurationTest {


    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private MarketDataMySqlRepository marketDataMySqlRepository;




    @Test
    public void readerTest() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();

      
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());

    }
}
```

When i try to launch my test i riceive this Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: According to the error, you need to define a bean of type `DataSource` in your test context.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch automatically creates tables in db, do you have a database launched and linked to your project ?

If not, use the application.properties file to bind your project to the database, Exemple for Postgres database, with db name dbName :

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbName
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

Comment: Yes, i have an application.properties with the following : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password    but doesn't work

Comment: have you another application.properties ? see src/test/rasources

Comment: Spring Batch does not create tables, it is Spring Boot that does that (if you instruct it to do so).

Comment: i have two .properties , one is application-dev.properties for main batch application e one is application.properties in src/test/resources with in memory H2 database for test

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself, maybe it can be useful to someone, I created a configuration class for my Datasource with a configuration bean inside:

```
public class DataSourceConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("sa");

    return dataSource;
}}
```

although i solved this problem now i have others lol, i hope it will be useful to someone :-)